# How can I unlist the result of pivot wider in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Does anyone know of a way to unlist the output from the pivot_wider function in R? The following code returns a list in each cell of column A and a list in each cell of column B. What I'd ideally like is the Item (e.g. Orange) repeated for each observation in the list cells A and B.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(111)
# What I have
data_bad <- tibble(
  Item = rep(c("Orange", "Lemon", "Sugar", "Parsley"),each = 6),
  Source = rep(c("A","A","A","B","B","B"), times = 4),
  Value = runif(length(Item))
) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Source, values_from = Value, values_fn = list(value = list))

# What I'd like
data_good <- tibble(
  Item = rep(c("Orange", "Lemon", "Sugar", "Parsley"),each = 6),
  A = runif(n = length(Item)),
  B = runif(n = length(Item))
)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `unnest` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data_bad %>% 
   unnest
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thank you! (I was trying to use unlist)

Comment: `unnest` function now shows a `Warning message:
'cols' is now required when using unnest().
Please use 'cols = c(A, B)`

Comment: @jpdugo17 i think it is a version triggered warning. thanks